# How to be consistent with Photoshop's "Replace Color" Tool?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-7

I am using Photoshop 7 and I use the *Replace Color* feature as I am changing the theme of a bunch of different pictures.

My issue is that *Replace Color* only has sliders that you can drag from an existing picked color to a new color and it shows you the offset in *Hue*, *Saturation* and *Lightness*.

[image]

What I want it to do is replace some selected color with a specific defined color.

I was hoping **Save** would save the exact color (in RGB, HSB or HTML#) but it seems to only save the offset.

Is this possible in Photoshop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Photoshop version I can simply click on the "Sample" color and set it from the resulting dialog.

I don't know if this option exists in Photoshop 7.

Comment: i dont see this in photoshop 7

Comment: Then maybe you should upgrade to a newer Photoshop version. If cost is a factor, I can recommend [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/).

Answer (score 0):

My PS is a bit old, but it should still work for you. First go to select "color range". You can then pick your color out of the image. You can lower fuzziness to select one specific color. Next set your background AND foreground color to the same color. This allows you to use the gradient tool to fill an entire selection with one specific color.

Answer (score 0):

I would say use the Select > Color Range instead. Select the color areas you want to change, and set your foreground color to the desired color. Then just use Shift+Alt+Delete to fill the selection with the foreground color.

If your pictures have tonal variation in the colored areas, you won't want some solid fill; so you might float a new layer above with a blending mode of Color. Then use paint bucket to fill the selection since Shift+Alt+Delete will not affect alpha.